# Various translations of "ticket"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario

The English word *ticket* (that is, a slip of paper used to grant access to something) can be translated several different ways in Spanish:

- boleto
- pasaje
- billete
- ticket
- entrada
- resguardo

What are the differences between these words? In what situations would each be used? Specifically, which are appropriate for a plane, bus, or train ticket?

Comment: Ticket translation ticket. Is almost the same with taxi.

Comment: *Taxi* is up there with *OK* and *coffee* as one of the most universal words, though that last one does change its sound quite a bit.

Comment: There are other regional terms for ticket I've found: *tique*, *tiquete*, and possibly *tiquet* - perhaps all Costa Rican variants.

Comment: actually not "ticket", but "tique" or "tiquete"

Comment: @vartec: [David lay says in his answer here that *ticket* is used at least in Chile](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/550/75)...

Comment: @hippietrail: that doesn't make it a word in Spanish.

Comment: What makes any word a word in a language is whether the people who use the language use the word. Personally I always use *boleto* in Spanish and I don't tell other people what words they should and shouldn't use.

Comment: @hippietrail: might be so, but this site is not dedicated to Spanglish, but to Spanish.

Comment: Calling it names doesn't make it not Spanish. Borrowed words doesn't make it not Spanish. Otherwise using *tique* or *tiquete* would make it "Franish" as much as using "ticket" would make it "Spanglish".

Comment: See [prescription](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription) vs. [description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_description).

Comment: In defense of the user hippietrail: I'm a Spaniard and I say ticket. Yes, it's an anglicism, but we use it.

Comment: Disagreeing is OK, especially with words that are used differently in different places. But try not to get into fights over it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Pasaje* and *billete* are usually used in the transportation sector (*pasaje de tren*, *billete de avión*, etc.). *Boleto* is commonly used in the lottery and gambling world (*boleto de lotería*), but can also be used in the same way as *pasaje* and *billete*.

*Entrada* refers to a ticket to a show or a generic event.

*Resguardo* is usually a paper that certifies something (a comercial transaction, a bureaucratic affair, a package delivery, the delivery of a document...).

Note I'm talking about the usage of these words in Spain.

Comment: The usual English word for *resguardo* is *receipt*.

Comment: @hippietrail, thanks, the word didn't come to my mind.

Comment: No problem. I had to check because the word I always used for *receipt* was *recibo*.

Comment: As I said in my answer there are a lot of highly localized usage there. In Argentina, for example, "billete" is for money or lottery ticket ONLY, "boleto" is for ground transportation ticket (bus, train, but never airplane or ship. Those use "pasaje") :). Also "boleto" is used in the sense you mentioned "resguardo", as in "boleto de venta" (a legal promise to sell a property)

Comment: @belisarius you're right; I was talking about what I've seen so far in Spain.

Answer (score 9):

Voy a colocar el significado coloquial de estas palabras en Chile, solo por referencia:

- boleto/boleta

  - trozo de papel que atestigua de algún suceso. Es común que se refiera a un recibo de pago.
- pasaje:

  - derecho de abordar a un transporte. También se refiere al trozo de papel que atestigua este derecho.
- billete:

  - reservado para moneda de papel.
- ticket:

  - igual que boleto pero no se usa para recibo de pago. Es común que se use en vez de *entrada*.
- entrada:

  - derecho de entrar a algun lugar. Común para conciertos, cine, etc. Se usa también para nombrar el trozo de papel que atestigua esto.
- resguardo / recibo:

  - no usado en Chile, pero se entiende que es un papel o comprobante en recibo de un pago o prenda.

Answer (score 6):

*Boleto, pasaje, billete and ticket* (and tiquete) have different local precise meanings, but are usually understandable by almost anyone.

*Entrada*, refers usually to a ticket you have to show up at the entrance (in the cinema, for example).

*Resguardo* is not an usual word for a ticket, but I heard it used referring to the part of the ticket stripped from the main body which allows you to exit from some place where you could only enter with a ticket and the going back in (showing the *resguardo*)

Comment: The usual English word for *resguardo* is *receipt*.

Comment: @hippi Receipt is usually translated as "recibo"

Comment: Indeed. But that's in the other direction. Welcome to the wonderful word of translation where symmetry as you know it is not guaranteed (-: